# Is it possible to use the terminal malloc_history when debugging on a iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, debugging, console, terminal

I've found malloc_history useful when testing on the iOS simulator, is it possible to configure it for a physical device (iPhone 4).

On the **console** I do get similar messages to this

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

Do I need to setup this file somewhere?

On the **terminal** I get this

```
malloc_history cannot examine process xxxx because the process does not exist.
```

Any direct advice / pointers to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck? I've had the same problem recently.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741985/malloc-history-cannot-examine-process-xxxxxx-because-the-process-does-not-exist. Looks like you cannot use malloc_history when debugging on a device, only with simulator.

Answer (score -2):

Try to fire up Instruments and use "Allocations".