# malloc_history cannot examine process xxxxxx because the process does not exist in iOS

Tags: ios, debugging, environment-variables, malloc-history

I added the below environment variables to my Project and set their values to YES.

NSDebugEnabled
   NSZombieEnabled
   MallocStackLogging
   MallocStackLoggingNoCompact

I followed the Procedures in http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease

I was able to find the Problem based on the Log generated. My doubt is when I tried to find the stack trace to find where the object was allocated, I got the below information:

**malloc_history cannot examine process 6963 because the process does not exist.**

Am I missing anything here?

Below is the Log Created:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I found the below link to be a good source of information on this:

[strange GDB error unable to trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910861/strange-gdb-error-unable-to-trace)

I am yet to test this.

Comment: I have got this problem the second time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found for myself, that malloc_history is unable to track memory log of the device while successfully tracking the simulators memory log. Try to simulate the problem on simulator and then use the malloc_history tool. (at least I've found it as the only way yet)

Comment: Are you sure you could not get this?

Comment: Nope, I'm not sure... Maybe I just didn't found the right way.

Comment: I confirmed that malloc_history can not be used while testing in Device. It works only in simulator.

Answer (score -1):

## Synatax:

**Shell malloc_history process_id memory_address**

Keep the track of **processid** Use the one when application starts.